# Issue with using angular material locally

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am working on a restricted network and we don't have npm, bower or can't reference google libraries or cdn and that's why we need to set up angular libraries locally. We need to use angular-material locally and reference it. I downloaded angular-material content along with animate, aria, messages and material. Also angular-material.css as angular-material.css and angular-material.js isn't available in that zip.

Injected ngMaterial to my app but then I get this [error](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24forceReflowProvider%20%3C-%20%24%24forceReflow%20%3C-%20%24%24animateQueue%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compile%20%3C-%20%24mdUtilmdTheming%20%3C-%20%24animateQueue) in my IE console

when broken to readable format:

> forceReflowProvider -> forceReflow  -> animateQueue -> animate ->  compile -> mdUtilmdTheming -> animateQueue

Why does this happen?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @SushobhNadiger Looks like he's using AngularJS 1.4.3.

Comment: Can you try loading the unminimized version of angularjs instead (i.e. `angular.js`)? It should output a more detailed error. And can you show us your source code?